# What is the meaning of "As a whole" in this sentence

Tags: vocabulary

> People responding to a survey are different from the target population as a whole.

If the phrase `as a whole` is taken out of the sentence, the meaning would still be the same correct?

If so, what extra meaning does the phrase add in this case?

Comment: The expression **as a whole** (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as-a-whole) means *when something such as a large group of people considered as a single unit and not as separate parts*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sense would be *distorted* in that case, because that would mean the respondents most likely *don't belong* to the target population and therefore, the survey is not held properly. The original sentence actually means that in practice, the respondents (who's **number is limited**) may represent the target population (**as a whole**) *not in exact manner*, being **different** from (hypothetical) **typical** representatives. So *as a whole* is an important part of the sentence.

Comment: Just to clarify, so "as a whole" is applied to both the respondents and the target population, not just the target population?

Comment: It is applied to the 'target population' only. Without this specification the sentence sounds like 'the respondents were not a part of the subject explored in the survey'.